# What happened to the parameters when the function was called?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking at how to format axis tick marks in matplotlib

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_ticker1.html

The link shows the following pieces of code

```
def millions(x, pos):
    'The two args are the value and tick position'
    return '$%1.1fM' % (x*1e-6)
```

I am having trouble with understanding what happened to the x, pos values when it is used

```
formatter = FuncFormatter(millions)
```

What is that concept called?

Comment: functor is the concept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line:

```
formatter = FuncFormatter(millions)
```

you are creating an instance of the `FuncFormatter` class, which is being initialised with the `millions` function. This is a class which matplotlib accepts as part of its api to format ticks. In the example, the `formatter` object is passed to the `set_major_formatter` method for the y axis so that ticks will be formatted with the `millions` function.

You can see how this works in the matplotlib source code. The class is defined as follows:

```
class FuncFormatter(Formatter):
    """
    User defined function for formatting

    The function should take in two inputs (tick value *x* and position *pos*)
    and return a string
    """
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, x, pos=None):
        'Return the format for tick val *x* at position *pos*'
        return self.func(x, pos)
```

So now the object stored in `formatter` will have an attribute `func` which points to the `millions` function. When matplotlib makes a call to the `formatter` object that you have passed it, it will pass the arguments (i.e. the values represented by the ticks) to the `millions` function which is pointed to by `self.func`

Since the `millions` function only formats the ticks based on the x value and not on the position, the definition of `millions` only includes the `pos` argument as a dummy placeholder. It must do this in order for there not to be an error when `self.func(x, pos)` is called by matplotlib when it formats the ticks.